# Using Crontab to restart putty

Tags: bash, cron, putty

I have been round and round looking for an answer to this problem. I imagine there is a key nugget of info that I am missing that will solve this issue, so hopefully you lovely devs can help me.

I am using tightvnc to remotely connect to my raspberry pi at home, which is running an arduino with serial output. I want to grab that serial output and slap it into a txt file, and to do this I am using putty's serial logging feature. It works splendidly, even has a date/time naming feature for generating useful log names. The issue is that I want to create a new log file periodically, and I have figured out how to start and stop the putty session using bash `.sh` scripts, but I want to automate that process.

**Note that I am open to alternative ways to restart my log file each day, but this is what I've found over the few days of research I've completed.

I would think it would be as simple as scheduling the scripts using crontab, however I am running into a perplexing issue when trying. I've scheduled two tasks, one to stop putty and one to start it back up again in a new terminal. The task that kills putty works in crontab and is executed using putty_killer.sh given below, but using a similar method to try to restart putty with the proper profile does nothing. I don't know if crontab outputs error logs but if it does I don't know where to find them. That would be helpful information, but mostly I just want to know why the restart won't work.

**putty_logger.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1
/usr/bin/lxterminal -e /usr/bin/putty -load Hydroponics_Test_Bed
```

**putty_killer.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
killall putty
```

**crontab -e**

```
# m h dom mon dow command
00 07 * * * /bin/bash /home/pit/sketchbook/putty_killer.sh
00 07 * * * /bin/bash /home/pit/sketchbook/putty_logger.sh
```

Like I said, putty_killer works fine, and then putty_logger does nothing. I've used these both in terminals outside of crontab and they work fine, but crontab doesn't seem to know what I'm asking for in putty_logger. Is there a syntax issue? Do I need to tell crontab to use bash instead of sh? How do? I'm swimming in information that I don't really know what to do with, so your help would be much appreciated!

INB4 1: I've tried executing the putty_logger without the putty_killer in crontab to no avail, so I don't think the putty_killer is preventing putty_logger from starting.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out guys! As it turns out, if there is a GUI component to your command you must tell crontab which display to mount it to. This can be done using export DISPLAY=:0 && your_command.

My final crontab entry to run putty turned out to be:

```
# m h dom mon dow command
00 07 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /bin/bash /home/pit/sketchbook/putty_killer.sh
00 07 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /bin/bash /home/pit/sketchbook/putty_logger.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

give 2>&1 > /tmp/somelog at the end of your lines, you can also turn on shell debugging with -x so you would have:

```
00 07 * * * /bin/bash -x /home/pit/sketchbook/putty_killer.sh 2>&1 > /tmp/somelog
```

ok to explain, linux doesnt need file extensions as windows and hence doesnt create them, so then you can check log file content in cli with e.g.:

```
cat /tmp/somelog
```

and you dont need putty for running ssh try to replace putty with:

```
ssh -i /home/someuser/somekey usename@yourserver 'somecommand'
```

Comment: I added what you said, but I'm not sure what it did. I created errorlog.txt in the path specified and tried a quick reschedule, but noting happened.  
  
EDIT sorry, tried to put my code in put enter sends comments.  

`# m h  dom mon dow   command 52 09 * * * /bin/bash -x /home/pi/sketchbook/putty_killer.sh 2>&1 /tmp/errorlog  
52 09 * * * /bin/bash -x /home/pi/sketchbook/putty_logger.sh 2>&1 /tmp/errorlog`

Comment: I don't know why my line breaks didn't work in the previous comment. Sorry for the shite formatting. It won't let me edit it anymore.

Comment: there is nothing in log?